# STM32F401 SDIO with DMA

Tags: sd, stm32f4, datalogger, dma, sdio

Please need help in:

1. Do somebody have a a working code that writes to sd card via sdio using FatFs and DMA?( data logger)
2. In a poling mode (without DMA) I am writing to .bin file and getting error when the file is 4096 bytes. Do you know how and where can I remove this limit?

Comment: you should write blocks of 512 bytes at once.

Comment: I am ...but I think my sdio-dma configurations have some trouble.... The code stacks in while loop that waiting for response that the writing completed ....but it never complete...

Comment: At point 2. you are saying in polling mode (no DMA) you have problems, too.  The DMA is even more complicated. Altrough I don't have a crystall ball to know what you are doing wrong, neither the sample code for data logger.